# No method prog() to build a ParseTree object

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I experience issues with ANTLR 4, using the visitor classes.
I try to write the following code:

```
import bla.gen.InputLexer;
import bla.gen.InputParser;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRFileStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputLexer lexer = new InputLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("pl_example.lp"));
        InputParser parser = new InputParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        parser.setBuildParseTree(true);
        ParseTree tree = parser.prog();
        ParserVisitor visitor = new ParserVisitor();
        visitor.visit();

    }
}
```

I try to mimic the code found in the book example here: 
https://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/source_code

(I have no access to the book, just the examples).

But I've got an error because the method parser.prog() does not exists...

I use ANTLR 4.5.

Do you know how to generate ParseTree with this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the method used to retrieve the parse tree is the same as the entry parse rule chosen. If you used a different name for the entry parse rule, the method will be called that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you deleted the initial symbol from you grammatic the LabeledExpr.g4 in the book, that is 'prog' and have one or more 'stats' 'stat+'
prog: stat+ ;
Then, not find the initial symbol to go through the tree.